# How do I use the STIX Font in Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, font

I just found out that Mac OS X 10.7 ships with [STIX fonts](http://www.stixfonts.org/abt_geninfo.html) (Scientific and Technical Information Exchange format). Can someone explain me how I can make use of these fonts or where there is a tutorial on proper use of these fonts?

> The mission of the Scientific and Technical Information Exchange
>   (STIX) font creation project is the preparation of a comprehensive set
>   of fonts that serve the scientific and engineering community in the
>   process from manuscript creation through final publication, both in
>   electronic and print formats.

Comment: Aren't these just a set of normal fonts designed to give high quality, consistent rendering of math equations and related text?  So if you are creating or reading such stuff you just select these as the font for whatever app you are using. There are reports that people use MathJax should disable them to avoid some problems.

Answer (score 2):

These fonts should get used automatically by standard marked-up text that calls for them.  Check this test site with FireFox 4 and up:

https://eyeasme.com/Joe/MathML/MathML_browser_test

Info on documentation of the fonts is at

http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/project/stixfonts/DocumentationOnly/STIXv1.0.0.pdf

Info on using STIX fonts with LaTeX is at

http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/the-unicode-math-package-for-xelatex-and-the-stix-fonts/